# improving yslow score on external js file with expiry date that you have no control of

Tags: javascript, html, performance, yslow

I am getting a grade C on my YSlow because I have the following files not having an expiry date:

[image]

If you can't see what are those files, mostly those are facebook sdks js, twitter share widget js, live chat javascript widget, crazy egg javascript widget, and google plus javascript sdk. So I have no control of how they set the expiry date for these files. So then I am stuck, what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can do much since the expire dates are set by the respective servers that each js file is loaded from. For FB at least you should take a look at this https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/02/how-to--optimize-social-plugin-performance/

Answer (score 0):

To follow on to Valentin's answer: you won't have control of things like the expiration date for scripts hosted by other services.

I would take a step back and look at the total amount of external JS that is being brought in and see if any can be combined, eliminated, or deferred loaded.

For example, look into [static social media share buttons](http://daniemon.com/blog/static-social-media-share-buttons/). For the external JS that is being loaded just to create the respective Share buttons, switching to these static versions could be a big performance improvement.